# Funcion Split en python

Tags: python

Tengo este trozo de programación en python:

```
billete = "Esto es un billete de 500 euros"

trocitos_de_billete = billete.split()

print(trocitos_de_billete)
```

Me pregunto que es lo que hace excatamente el ".split()", es decir ¿como sería ese programa sin el .split? ¿Qué es lo que hace exactamente?

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 2):

El método `str.split` permite separa una cadena usando un separador dado como argumento (que es otra cadena de cualquier longitud). Retorna una lista con las cadenas resultantes de partir la original cada vez que el separador se encuentra.

Si no se le pasan argumento separa por espacios en blanco (**no solo el espacio (`\s`), sino también `\t`, `\r`, `\n`, `\x0b` y `\x0c`**). Considerando cualquier número de ellos contiguos como un separador. Si la cadena empieza o termina con una secuencia de espacios en blanco no se generar una cadena vacía al inicio o final de la lista.

Una implementación un poco burda para éste caso concreto, separando por espacios, sería la siguiente:

```
billete = "Esto es un billete de 500 euros"


indice_inicial = None
for i in range(len(billete)):
    if billete[i] == " ":
        if indice_inicial is not None:
            trocitos_de_billete.append(billete[indice_inicial: i])
            indice_inicial = None 
    else:
        if indice_inicial is None:
            indice_inicial = i
            
if indice_inicial is not None:
    trocitos_de_billete.append(billete[indice_inicial:])
                
print(trocitos_de_billete)
```

Una implementación completa podría ser la siguiente:

```
from typing import List, Optional


def split(cadena: str, sep: Optional[str]=None, maxsplit: int=-1) -> List[str]:
    res = []
    
    # No se pasa separador
    if sep is None:
        índice_inicial = None

        for índice, carácter in enumerate(cadena):
            if carácter in ' \t\n\r\x0b\x0c' and índice_inicial is not None:
                res.append(cadena[índice_inicial: índice])
                índice_inicial = None
                maxsplit -= 1
                continue
            elif índice_inicial is None:
                if maxsplit == 0:
                    res.append(cadena[índice: ])
                    return res
                índice_inicial = índice  
        if índice_inicial is None:
            res.append(billete[índice_inicial: ])
        return res
    
    # Se pasa una cadena separadora
    lenght_sep = len(sep)
    lenght_cadena = len(cadena)
    índice = 0
    índice_inicial = 0
    while índice < lenght_cadena:
        if cadena[índice: índice + lenght_sep] != sep:
            índice += 1
        else:
            res.append(cadena[índice_inicial: índice - lenght_cadena])
            if (maxsplit:= maxsplit - 1) == 0:
                if cadena[índice: índice + lenght_sep] == sep:
                    índice += lenght_sep
                res.append(cadena[índice: ])
                return res
            índice = índice_inicial = índice + lenght_sep
    res.append(cadena[índice_inicial: ])
    return res
```

Es sin duda muy optimizable, especialmente el caso en el que se aporta un separador, hay mejores métodos de búsqueda de subcadenas que hacer slicings secuenciales sin duda, como el método de Boyer–Moore–Horspool, pero no pretendo que sea óptimo sino que se comporte como `str.split` y sea simple.

> ```
> >>> billete = "Esto es un billete de 500 euros"
>
> >>> split(billete)
> ['Esto', 'es', 'un', 'billete', 'de', '500']
>
> >>> split(billete, maxsplit=3)
> ['Esto', 'es', 'un', 'billete de 500 euros']
>
> >>> split(billete, sep="e", maxsplit=2)
> ['Esto ', 's un bill', 'te de 500 euros']
>
> >>> split(billete, sep="e")
> ['Esto ', 's un bill', 't', ' d', ' 500 ', 'uros']
>
> >>> split(billete, sep="E")
> ['', 'sto es un billete de 500 euros']
>
> >>> split(billete, sep="s")
> ['E', 'to e', ' un billete de 500 euro', '']
>
> >>> split(billete, sep="00")
> ['Esto es un billete de 5', ' euros']
>
> >>> split(billete, sep="foo")
> ['Esto es un billete de 500 euros']
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que hace split es devolverte una lista de string cuyo separador es la cadena que le pasas. Por ejemplo:

```
txt = "welcome to the jungle"
x = txt.split() # el separador es el espacio en blanco
print(x) # output: ['welcome', 'to', 'the', 'jungle']
```

Y en este otro caso:

```
txt = "hello, my name is Peter, I am 26 years old"
x = txt.split(", ") # el separador es una coma junto a un espacio en blanco
print(x) # output: ['hello', 'my name is Peter', 'I am 26 years old']
```

Comment: me refiero a como programar la funcion split sin utilizar split.

Comment: Puedes recorrer la cadena caracter a caracter y cuando te aparezca el indicado añadir un string nuevo a la lista

Answer (score 1):

Una implementación de split sin hacer uso de la función `split()` puede ser como esta:

```
string = 'hola como estas tu amigo'
split_val = []
temp = ''
for c in string:
    if c == ' ':
        split_val.append(temp)
        temp = ''
    else:
        temp += c
if temp:
    split_val.append(temp)

print(split_val)
```

El output del print es: `['hola', 'como', 'estas', 'tu', 'amigo']`

El ciclo for recorre todo el string letra por letra y la va agregando a **temp**, cuando **c** es igual a **vacio** entonces se agrega **temp** al **array** que es **split_val**.

Ejemplo funcional: [Paiza Python3](https://paiza.io/projects/koncRfv91fwGJP0UGTqaAQ)

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una implementación muy sencilla del método `split()`.
Primero se limpia la cadena de todos los separadores al principio y final. Nuevamente se le agrega un separador al final, para facilitar los cálculos.
Si el separador es una cadena vacía arrojará un `raise(TypeError)`, asi se comporta el `split()` incorporado en Python.

Ahora a través de un `while` se buscan las posiciones de todos los separadores. Si se encuentra alguno, se saca una subcadena [pos_inicial : pos_separador], y se añade a la lista palabras. Se actualiza la variable pos_inicial para que empiece desde donde se encontró la última ocurrencia del separador: `pos_inicial = pos_separador + long_separador`. 
Si no se encuentra ningún separador `pos_separador = -1`, entra en el `else`, lo cual termina el ciclo y se retorna la lista.

```
def split2(frase, sep=' '):
    long_separador = len(sep)
    if long_separador == 0:
        raise(TypeError("No puede haber un separador vacio"))
    frase = frase.strip(sep) # Limpiar de los separadores al principio o al final
    frase = frase + sep # Agregar el separador al final para facilitar los calculos
    palabras = []
    pos_inicial = 0
    while pos_inicial != -1:
        pos_separador = frase.find(sep, pos_inicial)
        if pos_separador != -1:
            palabras.append(frase[pos_inicial : pos_separador])
            pos_inicial = pos_separador + long_separador
        else:
            pos_inicial = pos_separador
    return palabras
```

Pruebas

```
print(split2(",Hola,como,estan,todos", ','))
# ['Hola', 'como', 'estan', 'todos']
print(split2("Hola mundo"))
# ['Hola', 'mundo']
print(split2("Hola,como,estan,todos", ','))
# ['Hola', 'como', 'estan', 'todos']
print(split2('"data 01",,"data 02",,"data 03"', ',,'))
# ['"data 01"', '"data 02"', '"data 03"']
print(split2("Hola mundo", '*'))
# ["Hola mundo"]
```

Answer (score -1):

De esta manera tambien funciona y me parecio una forma muy simple de solucionar ese reto.

```
def mysplit(strng):
    strng2 = strng.strip()
    strng2 += " "
    new_strng = ""
    lista = []
    if strng2 == " ":
        return lista
    else:
        for ch in strng2:
            if ch != " ":
                new_strng += ch
            else:
                lista.append(new_strng)
                new_strng = ""
    return lista
    
print(mysplit("Ser o no ser, esa es la pregunta"))
print(mysplit("Ser o no ser,esa es la pregunta"))
print(mysplit("   "))
print(mysplit(" abc "))
print(mysplit(""))
```

Comment: Hola Cristian, las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad ya que, sin una descripción de lo que hacen o cómo solucionan el problema, no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir más detalles. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información (y así ganarás tu primera medalla en el sitio). Saludos.